# How to serialize a class with a generic parameter as an interface with System.Text.Json?

Tags: c#, json, generics, system.text.json

I have the following classes to represent a report that can have different type of chart (pie, area...) with each chart type having specific property :

```
public class ReportDTO<TChart> where TChart : IChart
{
    public TChart ChartDTO { get; set; }
    public DateTime? From { get; set; }
    public DateTime? To { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; } = null!;
    public string? Subtitle { get; set; }
    public string? ChartTitle { get; set; }
}
         
public class ApexChartDTO : IChart
{
    public Chart? chart { get; set; } = null!;
    public DataLabels? dataLabels { get; set; }
    public Fill? fill { get; set; }
    public Stroke? stroke { get; set; }
    public Tooltip? tooltip { get; set; }
    public Grid? grid { get; set; }
    public Xaxis? xaxis { get; set; }
    public Yaxis? yaxis { get; set; }
    public string[]? labels { get; set; }
    public string[]? colors { get; set; }
    public Legend? legend { get; set; }
}

public class PieChartDTO : ApexChartDTO, IChart
{
    public PieChartDTO(int[] Series, string[] Labels)
    {
       //create a new piechart
       ...
    }
    public int[]? series { get; set; } = new int[0];
    public Plotoptions? plotOptions { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is when I try to serialize the class `ReportDTO<IChart>` using System.Text.Json  that has its property ChartDTO of type PieChartDTO I get a null value.

```
DateTime from = new DateTime(2022, 02, 13);
DateTime to = new DateTime(2022, 02, 19);
ReportDTO<IChart> pie = new ReportDTO<IChart>()
{
    Title = "My chart Title",
    From = from,
    To = to,
    Subtitle = "This is a Subtitle",
    ChartTitle = $"Data from {from:dd.MM.yyyy} to {to:dd.MM.yyyy}",
    ChartDTO = new PieChartDTO(new int[] { 0, 3, 4, 2 }, new string[] { "label1", "label2", "label3", "label4" })
};
string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(pie);
```

I get

```
{
  "ChartDTO": {},
  "From": "2023-02-13T00:00:00",
  "To": "2023-02-19T00:00:00",
  "Title": "My chart Title",
  "Subtitle": "This is a Subtitle",
  "ChartTitle": "Data from 13.02.2023 to 19.02.2023"
}
```

What should I do to have my ChartDTO serialize?

Comment: Is there a `ChartDTO` in the first place? You didn't post the code that constructs the `pie` object. Are you sure its `ChartDTO` property contains anything? Post code that actually reproduces the problem

Comment: JSON doesn't have interfaces, and JSON serializers don't care much about types, only about arrays and properties.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I edited my question with a more complete example.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos actually it is able to serialize an interface to a json object.

Comment: @shingo it serializes the object stored in the property, not the interface

Comment: @GreeNSparT there's no `ChartTitle` in `ReportDTO`.  Post code that actually compiles and reproduces the problem. It's far more likely you're looking at the wrong thing or wrong data, than System.Text.Json having such a fundamental bug

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've tried and it works, it's the first property `TChart ChartDTO` of `ReportDTO<T>`.

Comment: @GreeNSparT But I can't reproduce your issue: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lsCKxr

Comment: Instead of ` ReportDTO<IChart>()` use ` ReportDTO<PieChartDTO>()`

Comment: I simplified my code to post it here, that 's why some code was missing. I'll accept your answer, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
var pie = new ReportDTO<PieChartDTO>()
```

instead of

```
var pie = new ReportDTO<IChart>()
```

---

The problem is that `new ReportDTO<IChart>()` is used instead of `new ReportDTO<PieChartDTO>()`. The serializer inspects *and caches* the metadata of the `ReportDTO<IChart>` which means it sees `ChartDTO` as an `IChart`, not whatever else is stored there.

I'm able to reproduce this *ONLY* if `IChat` contains no properties. And adding quite a bit of missing code.

Using these classes:

```
public class ReportDTO<TChart> where TChart : IChart
{
    public TChart ChartDTO { get; set; }
    public DateTime? From { get; set; }
    public DateTime? To { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; } = null!;
    public string? Subtitle { get; set; }
}

public class Chart{}
public class Plotoptions {}

public class ApexChartDTO : IChart
{
    public Chart? chart { get; set; } = null!;
    public string[]? labels { get; set; }
    public string[]? colors { get; set; }
}

public class PieChartDTO : ApexChartDTO, IChart
{
    public int[]? series { get; set; } = new int[0];
    public string[]? labels { get; set; }
}
```

If `IChart` is just a marker interface:

```
public interface IChart {}
```

The following code

```
DateTime from = new DateTime(2022, 02, 13);
DateTime to = new DateTime(2022, 02, 19);
ReportDTO<IChart> pie = new ReportDTO<IChart>()
{
    Title = "My chart Title",
    From = from,
    To = to,
    Subtitle = "This is a Subtitle",    
    ChartDTO = new PieChartDTO{
        series=new int[] { 0, 3, 4, 2 }, labels=new string[] { "label1", "label2", "label3", "label4" }
    }
};
var json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(pie);
```

Produces

```
{
    "ChartDTO":{},
    "From":"2022-02-13T00:00:00",
    "To":"2022-02-19T00:00:00",
    "Title":"My chart Title",
    "Subtitle":"This is a Subtitle"
}
```

If I add properties to the interface, they appear in the output

```
public interface IChart
{
    public string[]? labels { get; set; }
}
```

This produces

```
{
    "ChartDTO":{
        "labels":[
            "label1",
            "label2",
            ...
```

If I use the correct type, though, I get all properties even if `IChart` is a marker interface:

```
public interface IChart{}
...
var pie = new ReportDTO<PieChartDTO>()
{
    Title = "My chart Title",
    From = from,
    To = to,
    Subtitle = "This is a Subtitle",    
    ChartDTO = new PieChartDTO{
        series=new int[] { 0, 3, 4, 2 }, 
        labels=new string[] { "label1", "label2", "label3", "label4" }
    }
};
```

The result is:

```
{
    "ChartDTO":{
        "series":[0,3,4,2],
        "chart":null,
        "labels":[...],
        "colors":null
    },
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change the generic parameter, You can also add one or more [JsonDerivedTypeAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonderivedtypeattribute?view=net-7.0)s on the interface to enable [polymorphic serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?pivots=dotnet-7-0).

```
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(PieChartDTO))]
public interface IChart
{
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately i'm using a clean architecture for my project, and my IChart class can't depend on PieChartDTO, but that would be the answer otherwise.